# How to handle List ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, list, try-catch

**Dictionary** class has **TryGetValue**
**List** I guess has only **Contains** (doesn't work based on indexes)

But this is not enough for how I do this..

when I add some kind of object to List.

I use `list.IndexOf(objectJustAdded);`  to get index location of object.

In my server a client has same list and just sends the index of list to server thats how server accesses the object stored on list.

Now I'm trying to prevent `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` which I don't think can happen, but I want to make server stable against hacker attack if someone sends malformed packet with bad index to list.. this exception may pop out.

What is best way to handle it? `Try/Catch?` anything better?

Comment: Just wrap it in a `Try/Catch` and handle the error from there.

Comment: Would involve wrapping the whole code I would like something like a if statement so i can just return (break) execution right away. Plus people always told me never rely on exceptions, try to make sure they don't happen by fixing them.

Comment: They're right, but only when you know what data is going into a piece of code. If you're leaving it open for a client, by all means wrap it it in a `Try/Catch` because you never know what they're going to upload. 

You could check to see if the Object is valid and if it is, then continue or break like you said.

Comment: Man my brain just exploded no wonder this exception shouldn't be handled this list doesn't work how I want it too work. Just found a big problem,   say object1 is index: 4    object2 is index : 5     remove object1.. and object2 isn't 5 anymore.. it's 4!.. I was hoping it wouldn't change now I gotta make my own list any alternative without custom making this idea? So if some user didn't get the new updated list.. pretty much defeats the purpose of using this system or making this program in general

Comment: The data is lets say a object that exists. Now lets say someone decides to remove it. It should get removed from all the clients who are connected to this server.. and the synchronization happens with the index's being static not dynamic the way it currently is. If all the indexes shift like they currently are then it would cause all kinds of problems. I guess I'll create a regular array of bool's and each index will be triggered on add object to list.. and closest index to beginning will be reused so no shifting of indexes.

Comment: Are you looping through the list items? Or just removing at a certain index?

Comment: Removing at certain, Pretty much i see only one way out keep looping a second array of bool's to find the closest (not active/false) spot near index 0 of bool array and reuse it this way the index's will stay synchronized with all clients. Might work.... dont know

Comment: The thing is, Dictionary/Array/List/etc all update when an index is removed. In the past, I've ran into this issue and I wrote code to work around it. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Great i'll look foward to it.. this new idea I had seems pretty solid keep looping from i=0 to MaxPossibleIndexes in bool array to find the first possible false trigger then break out.. the i variable will be the new used index. for the newest added object to list.. on remove of a object some how find the index.. most likely i'll have to store the index of the bool inside the object itself or there is no way to identify which it was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to loop through the indexes, you could do something like this:

```
double removedCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= lst.Count - 1; i++) {
  lst.RemoveAt(i - removedCount);
  removedCount = removedCount + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

send the hash code of the object instead and use a dictionary

Comment: What if the hashcodes are identical (more then one copy and different objects? can that happen?

Comment: google it, and you can allways implement your own GetHashCode.

Comment: Oh right I see. Not a bad idea.. i guess seems over doing it a bit though